# Not able to redirect https site to another url - nginx server block

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am trying to attach a promo subdomain to my site which is already on https, and then use a redirect url to redirect to another page in the site. For eg., basically if my site were `https://example.com` and had a page `https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo` then I want a browser redirect when I type in `https://promo.example.com` to this page. I have set up all the relevant AWS route 53 settings.

My nginx server blocks have this

```
   server {                                                                                                                                                                             
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            server_name www.example.com;
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name promo.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo;
    }
ssl_certificate /..path/..;
ssl_certificate_key //..path/..;
ssl_dhparam /..path/...;
ssl_trusted_certificate /..path/..;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers .......; //hidden
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_buffer_size 1400;
spdy_headers_comp 0;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;
resolver_timeout 10;

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/helper.conf;
    root /var/www/example/  ;
    index index.php index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

***Current behaviour:***

It redirects correctly when I type in `promo.example.com` directly **without** the https. But if I type in `https://promo.example.com` it just shows me example.com, with the url being `https://promo.example.com`

***Expected behaviour:***

If I type in `https://promo.example.com`, it should redirect to `https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo`

I can't put `https://promo.example.com` and then redirect with the server blocks, because nginx throws an error.

How can I redirect `https://promo.example.com` to go to `https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo`

Comment: I beleive that https uses port 443, so you should liste to port 443 for that

Comment: try adding this: `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Comment: Actually I have listen `443 ssl spdy` in my server declaration blocks, dont they basically do the same things?

Comment: I dont see it in above config, that's why I said that, http://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http, I think spdy shouldn't be there

Comment: If you go that page *promo.example.com* the **http://** (port 80) is automatically prepended in front. All you need is to add *listen 80* to latest server block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to use **Strict-Transport-Security** header the browser provides 301 redirect automatically by itself so this server block has never been used:

```
server {
    server_name promo.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo;
}
```

Port redirection 80->443 happens before even browser connected to server, so Nginx always serves latest server block based on port 443. This should help you:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name promo.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
server {
server_name promo.example.com;
rewrite ^ https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo permanent;
```

Comment: Same problem as before

Answer (score 2):

Each Server can have a single instance of https, which in this case is example.com, thus when https is prefixed to any of the url, irrespective of the urls, the user is redirected to the example.com.

To have the user redirected to the intended url with https, you need to have a separate port or a separate IP for that site.

Answer (score 2):

As per http://nginx.org/r/listen, the default for the listen directive is `listen *:80 | *:8000;`.

> If the directive is not present then either *:80 is used if nginx runs with the superuser privileges, or *:8000 otherwise.

As such, the snippets you've provided have no effect on https connections at all, since they don't apply to port 443 over ssl.

You haven't provided your ssl configuration snippets, nor the certificate details, for us to provide you with a complete answer, but once the above is understood, the answer would likely avail itself.

You can refer to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server in regards to configuring a single server to handle both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

P.S. In general, HTTPS itself doesn't plan nicely with subdomains, and unless you've paid extra, your certificate likely doesn't cover any of the subdomains, which means that it'll result in browser warnings should you or your users attempt to access such sites via the `https://` address scheme.

Comment: Updated the question, thanks, I look into that link now, but is it true that if I have to have https on a subdomain, it should be on a different IP?

Comment: @Slartibartfast, no, it only has to be a different IP if you have a different certificate for it.  If your present certificate doesn't cover `promo.example.com` (either explicitly, or via `*.example.com`), and you decide to buy another separate certificate for such subdomain, then, yes, it would be advisable to have an extra IP for such extra certificate, to ensure the overall compatibility with slight older clients.

Comment: Thats ok then,  my cert covers *.example.com , but still cant get https://... promo.example.com to redirect (it remains at example.com but with the url changed) and http://.... redirects correctly

Comment: Give us more details if you want more help.  However, from personal experience, some browsers hard-cache `301` redirects (I only use `302` for this reason), so, you may be hitting the cached copy (best way to avoid this is test with `curl`).  Another point worth considering -- why do you need this in the first place? Extra latency from domain resolution, short-lived TLS connection, plus redirect itself, [would only serve to decrease the likelihood that a purchase would be made](http://www.conversionconference.com/blog/case-study-how-making-pages-2-seconds-faster-boosted-conversions-by-66/).

Comment: @Slartibartfast, come to think of your IP address question, did it not work to simply add `listen 80; listen 443 ssl spdy;` within your `promo.example.com` block?  If nothing else is working and you're feeling desperate, perhaps simply putting something like `if ($host = "promo.example.com") {return 301 https://example.com/xyz/xyz/promo;}` within your `location /` of the main `https` `server` would do the trick?  (Plus, don't forget to amend the `server_name` to have `promo.example.com`, too.)

Comment: Nope, nothing I've tried has worked so far, currently I've just gone with the http version to the public and https redirect when someone clicks on it. But to make it feel more secure to someone clicking on it, I'd like to make it https. Yes, if I dont get alternative answers, I 'll probably end up trying for the redirect IF. Will come back with my solution, and if that's what I do, will mark as answer if you can update the answer with the above comment

Comment: It sounds like you might want to establish something like a `/go/` namespace; putting links on `https://example.com/` to `https://promo.example.com/`, only to redirect back to `https://example.com/abc/xyz/promo` sounds very inefficient!

Comment: Nope, not my upvotes :) I am yet to try the Strict - Transport - Security alternative though

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to work around this:

- Have a wildcard certificate for *.example.com, so all subdomains can share the same certificate.
- Run each SSL site at a different IP address. This way, the webserver knows which SSL certificate it can send to the browser. - by inspecting the IP address which received the incoming connection.